# I want that when the user moves inside the a-frame, a wind animation appears around him. what an effect that is going fast

Tags: html, animation, 3d, aframe, virtual-reality

I am trying in A-frame when you move inside the eframe you will see animation winds around the camera. And I don't know how to do it if any of you help me with this problem I would appreciate it.

I was trying to do it with GPT chat and it doesn't understand what I really want and it gives me this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=aframe+animation+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.